# How to add vector to tibble as a variable (column)

Tags: r, vector, dplyr, tidyverse, tibble

I have vector `vec<-1,2,3`. I have tibble that looks like:

```
first | second 
1     |1
1     |1
1     |1
```

Now I need to add vector `vec` to my existing tibble as variable (column) so that tibble should look like:

```
first | second | third
1     |1          |1
1     |1          |2
1     |1          |3
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is related to your other question, and I think they're both based on the misunderstanding of what a tibble is: it's still a data frame. Something you could do with a data frame (`df$x <- new_vector` here, `cbind(df1, df2)` in the other), you can generally do with a tibble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

tib <- tibble(first  = rep(1, 3),
       second = rep(1, 3)) 
vec <- c(1,2,3)

tib %>%
  mutate(third = vec)
```